# Configuring Laravel Homestead (Vagrant) and xdebug on Visual Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, xdebug, homestead

I have been trying to configure xDebug on VSCode with the "PHP Debug" extension to work with my local Homestead. Somehow it doesn't work at all. I've been trying different configuration changes but to no success.

Here are my config on the Vagrant box and in VSCode:

```
/etc/php/7.1/fpm/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini
zend_extension=/usr/lib/php/20160303/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_connect_back = 0
xdebug.remote_host = 192.168.0.104
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.max_nesting_level = 512
xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
xdebug.remote_log=/var/log/xdebug.log
```

And here is my config in VSCode:

```
launch.json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for XDebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "serverSourceRoot": "/home/vagrant/projects/Projectname",
            "localSourceRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",            
            "port": 9000,
            "log": true
        }
    ]
}
```

When I start a debugging session in VSCode I get this output in the debug window:

```
<- launchResponse
Response {
  seq: 0,
  type: 'response',
  request_seq: 2,
  command: 'launch',
  success: true }
```

But when running my app it doesn't stop at any of my breakpoints.

Any idea on what could be wrong? Do I need to map any port of my VM to my host in `Homestead.yaml`?

Answer (score 4):

I know i'm late to answer this question, but maybe this post helps others to save time:

I was able to debug in PHP code VSCode using vagrant doing the following steps:

1. Install the VSCode extension `"PHP Debug"`
2. Edit the `"launch.json"` file:

   ```
   {
     "version": "0.2.0",
     "configurations": [
         {
            "name": "Listen for XDebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9000,
            "localSourceRoot": "/your/host/php/dev/path/to/project-name",
            "serverSourceRoot": "/home/vagrant/dev/project-name"
         },
         {
            "name": "Launch currently open script",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "port": 9000
         }
      ]
   }
   ```
3. Connect via **ssh** to the homestead machine executing
   `vagrant ssh`
4. go to the folder

   > cd /etc/php/7.1/fpm/conf.d/
5. Edit the file "*`20-xdebug.ini`*" and validate that the port 9000 is configured

   Execute `sudo vim 20-xdebug.ini`.

   Edit the lines:

   `xdebug.remote_enable = 1
     xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
     xdebug.remote_connect_back = 1
     xdebug.max_nesting_level = 500
     xdebug.remote_port = 9000`
6. Save and exit.

   Press the [Escape] key.
   Type : SHIFT Z Z
7. Reboot `PHP` executing:
   `sudo service php7.1-fpm restart`

hope it helps!

Comment: This leads to missing property request. Attribute "Request" is missing from the chosen debug configuration.

Comment: localSourceRoot and serverSourceRoot are deprecated. Instead of:
         "localSourceRoot": "/your/host/php/dev/path/to/project-name",
         "serverSourceRoot": "/home/vagrant/dev/project-name"

use:
"pathMappings": {
""/home/vagrant/dev/project-name"" : "/your/host/php/dev/path/to/project-name"
}